# Should $found_posts be returned as string in 'found_posts' filter hook?

Tags: posts, wp-query, pagination, query

In general a function that hooks into the `found_posts` filter looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'found_posts', 'adjust_offset_pagination', 10, 2 );
function adjust_offset_pagination( $found_posts, $query ) {
    $offset = 10;

    if ( $query->is_posts_page ) {

        return( $found_posts - $offset );

    }
}
```

I noticed that when I did a `var_dump` of `$found_posts` like this in a template (that's accessible publicly):

```
<?php global $wp_query; var_dump( $wp_query->found_posts ); ?>
```

Without the function in place, the output (below) said `$found_posts` returns a string.

```
string(2) "19"
```

But with the function in place, `$found_posts` returned an integer.

```
int(9)
```

Since by default `$found_posts` returns a string, should it it be returned as a string in our functions too?

I mean, should our function look like this instead?

```
add_filter( 'found_posts', 'adjust_offset_pagination', 10, 2 );
function adjust_offset_pagination( $found_posts, $query ) {
    $offset = 10;

    if ( $query->is_posts_page ) {

        $found_posts = $found_posts - $offset;
        return "$found_posts";

    }
}
```

**PS:** The function works either way though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all integers in WordPress are treated as strings.

If you try to `var_dump($post->ID);` inside a loop you notice also post id is a string.

Normally this is not a problem because of PHP auto type casting feature.

This can be a problem, when you do strict comparison, like `1 === $post->ID` or `in_array(1, $ids, true);` but this **never happen in core for integers** (in core strict comparison is used only for some strings or to differe `0` from `false`).

Out of core (plugin, themes), is close to impossible (and close to crazy) that someone code something like:

```
$found_posts === "1"
```

so feel free to return integers as integers, (that is the right way) you'll have no problems: the reason that core sometimes is bad, is not a reason to being bad too.

Just be aware that if you want to use strict comparison (that's better) you have to manual type cast any WordPress integer:

```
(int) $found_posts === 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of PHP's variable handling, they are all interchangable. I would guess that `$found_posts` began it's life as an `int` and somewhere along the line it was cast to a `string`. Since you already know that value can only ever be a number, I would return it as an `int` and let PHP cast it to whatever it needs to be.